# How to compare the data and choose the TOP 2 from multiIndex dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How to compare the data and choose the TOP 2 or TOP5 from multiIndex dataframe in pandas? You see in this example, if `foo` only gets one record, it will be chosen only one. But if there are three records, TOP2 records will be chosen.

For example:

```
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz','baz', 'baz', 'qux', 'qux','qux', 'qux','foo']),
          np.array(['AA', 'AB', 'AC','AD', 'BA', 'BB', 'BC', 'CA', 'CB', 'CC', 'CD', 'DA'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(12, 1), index=arrays)
df
```

OUT:

```
         0
bar AA  -0.754077
    AB   0.924327
    AC   0.146192
    AD  -0.718730
baz BA  -0.143378
    BB   1.098409
    BC   0.703452
qux CA   0.729626
    CB   0.232755
    CC   0.827796
    CD   0.914639
foo DA  -0.289108
```

Finally, I want to choose like this:

```
         0
bar AB   0.924327
    AC   0.146192     
baz BB   1.098409
    BC   0.703452
qux CC   0.827796
    CD   0.914639
foo DA  -0.289108
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
np.random.seed(234)
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz','baz', 'baz', 'qux', 'qux','qux', 'qux','foo']),
          np.array(['AA', 'AB', 'AC','AD', 'BA', 'BB', 'BC', 'CA', 'CB', 'CC', 'CD', 'DA'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(12, 1), index=arrays)
print (df)
               0
bar AA  0.818792
    AB -1.043551
    AC  0.350901
    AD  0.921578
baz BA -0.087382
    BB -3.128885
    BC -0.969733
qux CA  0.934666
    CB  0.043866
    CC  1.425216
    CD -0.557063
foo DA  0.926824
```

Solution with [`SeriesGroupBy.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html):

```
s = df.groupby(level=0)[0].nlargest(2).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print (s)
bar  AD    0.921578
     AA    0.818792
baz  BA   -0.087382
     BC   -0.969733
foo  DA    0.926824
qux  CC    1.425216
     CA    0.934666
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

If need avoid sorting of `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(level=0, sort=False)[0]
       .nlargest(2)
       .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
       .to_frame())
print (df1)

               0
bar AD  0.921578
    AA  0.818792
baz BA -0.087382
    BC -0.969733
qux CC  1.425216
    CA  0.934666
foo DA  0.926824
```

Another solution, working in [pandas 0.23.0+](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#sorting-by-a-combination-of-columns-and-index-levels) with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df.index.names = ['lvl1','lvl2']
df.columns = ['a']
s = df.sort_values(['lvl1', 'a'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby(level=0).head(2)
print (s)
                  a
lvl1 lvl2          
bar  AD    0.921578
     AA    0.818792
baz  BA   -0.087382
     BC   -0.969733
foo  DA    0.926824
qux  CC    1.425216
     CA    0.934666
```

Comment: Thanks..it's perfect. But when I use it in my real data, ValueError happened. Why?

Comment: sample data great.

Comment: Both solution failed?

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-274-6c61403d35ad> in <module>()
----> 1 city_net4.groupby(level=0, sort=False)['count'].nlargest(2).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).to_frame()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    849                                                             *args, **kwargs)
    850                     except (AttributeError):
--> 851                         raise ValueError
    852 
    853         return wrapper

ValueError:

Comment: And second one?

Comment: second one ok! -^^-    s = df.sort_values(['lvl1', 'a'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby(level=0).head(2)

Comment: @runningman - Super, I think problem should be in sorting in `MultiIndex` :)